# Cannot import System.Windows.Window Class in a console application C#?

Tags: c#, using

just like i said in the title, i am unable to use the [Window class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window(v=vs.110).aspx) in my c# console application in visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from reference to `System.Windows` assembly you also need to add references to `PresentationCore`, `PresentationFramework` and if you want to use xaml then `System.Xaml`.

Most likely you will also need reference to `WindowsBase` assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on references select Add Reference go to Framework and select System.Windows.

Here is the screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add the reference. To add it open the *Solution Explorer*, right click onto *References*, select *add Reference*, search for *window* and select the *System.Windows* item. Now you can import `System.Windows` and use the `Window` class.

However you can't use it as you probably expected - for more information on that read through the link you provided.

Comment: I added the reference and still am unable to import. Im trying to get the IntPtr hWnd of the current window...